# Airflow Remote logging doesn't work for both scheduler & dag_process_manager logs

Tags: airflow

Hi based on airflow [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/howto/write-logs.html?highlight=logs)  I am able to set up cloud/remote logging.

Remote logging is working for dag and task logs but it's not able to back up or remotely store following logs of.

- scheduler
- dag_processing_manager

I am using docker_hub airflow docker image.